# Why would a hollow cylinder lose a race with a solid one?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Apart from the physics stuff which clearly shows why the hollow cylinder will lose:
$ T = RF = Iα = I* a/R$, since both F and a are missing we use the second equation F = ma:

Here are the forces involved:

$ma = mgsinΘ - F$, solve for F on the 1st equation then plug it for the one here.

Add $Ia/R^2$ to both sides, then take common a.
$ma = mgsinΘ - Ia/R^2$

Multiply both sides by $R^2$:

$a = MR^2gsinΘ/MR^2 + I$, plug the value for I

$I = 1/2MR^2$ for solid cylinder.

$I = MR^2$ for hollow cylinder.

$a(solid) = 2/3gsinΘ$

$a(hollow) = 1/2gsinΘ$

So now it is clear that the solid cylinder would win since it has larger acceleration compared to the hollow one.

But why? I might say that it has to do with inertia since the solid cylinder's moment of inertia is less than the hollow one, but we know that mass and radius are independent of acceleration as you can see the equations above there's no, M or R.

Is there an explanation for that?

Comment: Since the value of the moment of inertia determines the final acceleration then it is related to it, by other means, yes, it is the smaller moment of inertia of the solid cylinder that made it accelerate faster than the hollow one. Its smaller value made it possible that the final acceleration would be 2/3gsin0.

Comment: pick up a wheel and a rod of the same mass and try to rotate them with your hands. see which one rotates more easily.

Comment: consider a super-hollow cylinder, where the cylinder is connected to a >> larger wheel vs a super-interior cylinder, where the cylinder is mostly hollow with a >> dense weight at the center. at the limit, the >> wheel connected to a cylinder will not roll at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one considers a cylinder with moment of inertia $I$, radius $R$ and mass $m$ rolling down an inclined plane, the rotational energy will be
$$
E_{\text{rot}} = \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2~,
$$
where $\omega$ is the angular velocity. The translational energy is
$$
E_{\text{trans}} = \frac 12 m v^2~,
$$
with $v$ as the translational velocity. Assuming the cylinder does not slide, it holds $v = R \omega$, so the total kinetic energy of the cylinder is
$$
E_{\text{tot}} = \frac 12 I \omega^2 + \frac12 \frac{m \omega^2}{R^2} = \frac 12 \left( I + \frac{m}{R^2} \right) \omega^2~.
$$
This clearly shows that as potential energy is converted to kinetic energy during the decent of the cylinder, the angular velocity $\omega$ changes. The rate of this change is determined by $I$, $m$ and $R$, so for the same mass and radius, it is indeed the moment of inertia $I$ which determines how fast the cylinder becomes.

Now considering the second part of your question, about why the mass does not enter in the expression of the acceleration: The reason for this is, that the acceleration is due to gravity, which couples to the mass, so a higher mass means a higher moment of inertia but also a stronger force.

Answer (score 0):

The gravitational potential energy is converted to translational kinetic energy $\frac 12 mv^2$ and rotational kinetic energy $\frac 12 I_{\rm com}\omega^2$.
If there is no slipping $v=r\omega$ so the total kinetic energy is $\frac 12 mv^2\left(1+\frac{k^2}{r^2} \right)$ where $I_{\rm com} = m k^2$ and $k$ is the radius of gyration.

The larger $k$ is in relation to $r$ the more of the kinetic energy goes to rotation.
If all the mass were concentrated on the rim of radius $r$ then $k=r$ and half the kinetic energy is translational and half rotational with the consequence that the cylinder with the mass concentrated on the outside loses out to the solid cylinder which has a radius of gyration of $\frac {r}{\sqrt 2}$.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the problem in terms of energy to get an intuitive understanding. At any point along the incline, the potential and kinetic energy can be related
$$-PE = mg \Delta h = KE = \frac{mv^2}{2} + \frac{I \omega^2}{2} .$$
Here $\Delta h$ is the decrease in height, $v$ is cylinder speed, and $\omega$ is angular speed. Given $\omega = \frac{v}{a} $, we can write:
$$ v = \sqrt{\frac{2 m g \Delta h}{\left ( m + \frac{I}{a^2} \right ) }} $$

How should we interpret this? At any point, the solid cylinder will be moving faster because its moment of inertia is smaller. The two cylinders would have the same kinetic energy. However, for the solid cylinder, less kinetic energy is required to rotate the cylinder at a given rate, so more can go into translational motion. That's because mass is distributed closer to the axis of rotation for the solid cylinder, so more of it is moving slower at a given rotation rate.

Answer (score 0):

The total energy is:

$$E=\frac 12 m\,v^2+\frac 12 I\,\omega^2+m\,g\,h$$

at $~t=0~$ the energy is:

$$E_0=\frac 12 m\,g\,h_0$$

both object start with velocity equal zero at hight equal $~\frac 12 h_0$

with the conservation of the energy $~(E=E_0)~$ and the rolling without sliding $~(\omega=\frac vr)~$

you obtain

$$v^2=\frac{m\,g\,r^2\,(h_0-2\,h)}{m\,r^2+I}$$

the velocity is maximal for $~h=0$

$$v^2_{\rm max}=\frac{m\,g\,r^2\,h_0}{m\,r^2+I}$$

and because the inertia $~I~$ of the hollow  cylinder is greater then the massiv cylinder

$$v^2_{\rm hollow}< v^2_{\rm massiv}$$

---

$$I_{\rm hollow}=m\,(r_0^2+r^2)$$

$$I_{\rm massiv}=m\,r^2$$